# SQL like query features in Google App Script to pull data from Google Sheets

Tags: sql, sqlite, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to build a Google Apps Script web app that will pull data from a Google sheet and display it in rows and columns in an HTML page in the browser.

By following the samples etc I wrote this code that WORKS!

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService
       .createTemplateFromFile('Report3')
       .evaluate();
}

function getData(){

var spreadsheetId = '1Z6G2PTJviFKbXg9lWfesFUrvc3NSIAC7jGvhKiDGdcY';
var rangeName = 'Payments!A:D';

var values = Sheets
             .Spreadsheets
             .Values
             .get(spreadsheetId,rangeName)
             .values;
return values;

}
```

the data lying in columns A,B,C,D is getting pulled and being displayed correctly through the following HTML template

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
```

Instead of getting all the rows and all the columns from A,B,C,D I would like to run an SQL Query to retrieve some of the columns with a WHERE clause like SQL. I understand that the =QUERY() function that works in the spreadsheet does not work inside the GAS. So my next attempt was to retrieve SOME of the rows by using a getBatch method .. and this is where I get ERRORs

in this case, i want to exclude column C and get only A,B and D,E
the code that throws an error is as follows :

```
function getData2(){

var spreadsheetId = '1Z6G2PTJviFKbXg9lWfesFUrvc3NSIAC7jGvhKiDGdcY';

/* var rangeName1 = 'Payments!D'; */
/* var rangeName2 = 'Payments!A'; */
var values = Sheets
             .Spreadsheets
             .Values
             .batchGet(spreadsheetId,{ranges: ['Payments!D:E', 'Payments!A:B']})
             .values;
return values;

}
```

In the corresponding HTML template, all that changes is getData is replaced with getData2

```
<? var data = getData2(); ?>
```

with this code, I get the following error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 6, file
>   "Code", project "Report003")

Now I have two questions :

1. What is wrong in my code and how can i fix it?
2. Is it possible to use SQLite to simplify the process of extracting the desired rows and columns

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930389/can-the-google-spreadsheet-query-function-be-used-in-google-apps-script) but I am not able to understand the answer adequately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to perform data manipulations with the query to the data source. The syntax of the query language is similar to SQL

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
 // SpreadsheetApp.openById("SSID"); // To define the oAUTH Scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
 var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  output.token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  return output
        .evaluate()
        .setTitle('SQL Query');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="dataTable"><h4>Loading...</h4></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(loadEditor);

      function loadEditor() {
        var queryString = encodeURIComponent("SELECT A,B,D,E where A!= 'JACK'");
        var SSID = "ADD YOUR SPREADSHEET"
        var SHEET_NAME = "SHEET NAME"
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key='+SSID+'&sheet='+SHEET_NAME+'&oauth_token=<?=ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()?>&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
        query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
        console.log(response)
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        console.log(data);
        var chartTbl = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('dataTable'));
        chartTbl.draw(data);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe that this will work, but I have found another simpler way that is given below.

Comment: Have used both approaches, the one described in this answer and the other that I have given below. The one described in this answer is better.

Answer (score 8):

I finally understood what [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930389/can-the-google-spreadsheet-query-function-be-used-in-google-apps-script) was and modified it as given below. Now we can use any SQL that is supported by the QUERY() function.

```
function mostSQL(){

var spreadsheetId = '1Z6G2PTJviFKbXg9lWfesFUrvc3NSIAC7jGvhKiDGdcY';
var targetRange = 'Payments!A:G';
var SQL = 'select A, G where G >= 700 and G <= 800'
var Query = '=QUERY('+targetRange+',\"'+SQL+'\")'

var currentDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)
var tempSheet = currentDoc.insertSheet();

var pushQuery = tempSheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(Query);
var pullResult = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

currentDoc.deleteSheet(tempSheet); 

return pullResult;

}
```