# How to use Google sheets query or Google visualization api from apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am using a Google Script bound to a Google Sheet to programatically generate the following query:

`=query('16 Jul - 20 Jul Responses'!A1:I31, "SELECT C WHERE D = 'Available'", 0)`

Is there any way in Google Scripts to parse an object representation of that query's results? I'd like to be able to code something like:

`var queryString = '=query('16 Jul - 20 Jul Responses'!A1:I31, "SELECT C WHERE D = 'Available'", 0)';
var results = new Query(queryString);
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var result = results[i];
  // do something
}`

As far as I can tell, the Query object doesn't exist unless you are working with a Google Web App. Is this true? Or is there a way to implement this idea?