# How to implement the makeApiCall() method after migrating Google Sheets API v3 to v4 with Oauth Authorization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

Google has build v4 of the Google Sheets API but the documentation of this is still at v3. There are no full examples of how to implement a simple OAuth authentication with Google Sheets API v4.

I see a migration guide [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration) and I also see a partial example [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
But a full example is nowhere to be found. 
The "current" version is [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization) and it was last updated in October 2018 without providing a v4 example.

Let's say that after I authorize the user, I'm trying to read a particular spreadsheet in workbook2 and I'm explicitly specifying what columns I need. Then I present that information with Google Visualization API.

So, here's how I do it in Google Sheets v3 legacy.

```
function makeApiCall() {
var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A,B,C,E,H');
   var tqURL = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*yourspreadsheetid*/gviz/tq?gid=*yourworkbookid*&headers=1&tqx=responseHandler:handleTqResponse' + '&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token));
      tqURL.send(handleTqResponse);
}

function handleTqResponse(resp) {
  var dataTable = resp.getDataTable();
}
```

For v4, if I follow this partial example [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), how do I convert the tqURL to a GET method? and how can I still get the response (rsp) as a DataTable()?

```
    function makeApiCall() {
  var params = {
    spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',  // all clear here
    //what about workbook gid?
    // The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
    ranges: [],  // [A:A,B:B,C:C,E:E,H:H) ????
    includeGridData: false,
   //no need to include the access_token here?
  };

  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get(params);
  request.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.result);
  //var dataTable = responce.getDataTable(); ?? 
  }, function(reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have already been able to use Sheets API.

  - Sheets API is enabled at API console.
  - The access token can be used for retrieving values from the Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the values of `A:A,B:B,C:C,E:E,H:H` from a sheet.
- You want to retrieve the dataTable using `getDataTable()` from the values retrieved by Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I modified your script in your question. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve values from `A:A,B:B,C:C,E:E,H:H`, use the method of values.get in Sheets API.

  - In this case, at first, the values of `A:H` are retrieved and the values of the column A, B, C, E and H are retrieved.
- In order to retrieve the dataTable using `getDataTable()`, use ChartWrapper Class.

#### Modified script:

```
function makeApiCall() {
  var params = { // Modified
    spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',
    range: 'Sheet1!A:H', // Retrieve the values of "A:H".
  };
  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params); // Modified
  request.then(function(response) {
    var values = response.result.values.map((e) => [e[0], e[1], e[2], e[4], e[7]]); // Added
    var w = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({dataTable: values}); // Added

    var dataTable = w.getDataTable();

  }, function(reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When the method of values.get in Sheets API is used, please use a1Notation for the range. So in this case, the range becomes `Sheet1!A:H`. This means "A:H" of "Sheet1".

#### References:

- [values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject)

If I misunderstood your question and the result was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you! This looks extremely promising. it looks like I'm receiving a lot of errors now because every column is considered a string. How do I specify in the "values" variable the format of each column?

Comment: @Elnoob Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure about the values you are using, for example, how about adding ``valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE"`` to ``params``? I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm about the issue.

Comment: I should be the one apologizing. I absolutely appreciate your response. This solved the issue. Thanks a lot! I can now use the v4 without requesting the dreaded "feeds" scope that asks for too much from a user. Thanks again!

Comment: One more issue, although I'll try to solve it myself tomorrow. It looks like the var values = response.result.values.map((e) => [e[0], e[1], e[2], e[4], e[7]]) doesn't do anything. It still brings all the columns (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)

Comment: @Elnoob Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About ``var values = response.result.values.map((e) => [e[0], e[1], e[2], e[4], e[7]])``, for example, how about modifying to ``var values = response.result.values.map(function(e) {return [e[0], e[1], e[2], e[4], e[7]]})`` without using the arrow function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is an analog for the [Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) in the Sheets API(V4). Technically, the visualization API isn't really a part of legacy Sheets API (V3). If anything its a part of the Charts API. So you should be able to continue using it.

You can even use it server-side directly in GAS (see [Using Bound Google Scripts to Generate a Query Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51327982/6586255)).

Comment: I'm not replacing the actual Visualization API, just the connection part to take advantage of Google sheets v4 since that's where my data is coming from. It worked.

Comment: @Elnoob What makes you think query is using v3?

Comment: @TheMaster ah, you are right. What the hell? The whole reason I wanted v4 is to be able to change the scopes "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly". Is that not yet possible in google visualization api/charts api?

Comment: @Elnoob Should be possible. I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: Yeap, it worked but again, only if I follow the methods @Tanaike posted. If I attempt to pass a query string it fails. His method works perfectly except the chart doesn't like the dateformat and says that the "Column 3 is not a date" when in fact it is